# Why does my jQuery "complete" callback break in Chrome & Safari but work fine in FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have some problem with this jQuery code. I'm new at this but it works in FF and yet breaks in Chrome and Safari. Grateful for suggestions in any way.

```
 $('#level1nav ul li a:last').click(function () {

 $(lastBlock).animate({height:"400px"}, {queue:false, duration:500, 
    complete: function() 
        $(line).animate({width:"0px"}, {queue:false, duration:500, 
            complete: function() {window.location="?info"}
        })
    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: How does it break? What does it do?

Comment: What is the $(lastBlock) is lastBlock a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
complete: function() 
    $(line).animate({width:"0px"}, {queue:false, duration:500, 
        complete: function() {window.location="?info"}
    })
```

You're missing opening and closing curly braces for the outer function body. It should look like this:

```
complete: function()
{  $(line).animate({width:"0px"}, {queue:false, duration:500, 
      complete: function() {window.location="?info"}
  })
}
```

This works in Firefox because [JavaScript 1.8 introduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.8#Expression_closures) a "shorthand" for functions that doesn't require the braces in limited circumstances:

> #### Expression closures
>
> This addition is nothing more than a shorthand for writing simple functions, giving the language something similar to a typical Lambda notation.
>
> ...
>
> This syntax allows you to leave off the braces and 'return' statement - making them implicit. There is no added benefit to writing code in this manner, other than having it be syntactically shorter.